# Text values are changed in customized listview when scroll the listview in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my application am using customized list-view with text view,edit-text and buttons.When i click the button in "0"Th position and am change the text view values in "0"Th position .when i scroll down the list-view the values in "0"Th position text view changed to what ever in initial state.

**My base adapter class**

```
public class sample extends BaseAdapter{

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
Activity activity;

public sample(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

class ViewHolder {

    Button order;
    TextView item_name, order_qty;
    EditText et_quantity;

}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_custom, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.order = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.order);
        holder.item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        holder.order_qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_count);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
try{
    HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);

    holder.item_name.setText(map.get("name"));

    //Log.v("Available or not", ""+map.get("available"));


}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}


holder.order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //here am click the button to change order count text value
        int qty = Integer.valueOf(""+holder.order_qty.getText().toString());

        qty++;

        holder.order_qty.setText(""+String.valueOf(qty));
 }
});


return convertView;
}

}
```

i don't know why the text values changed to initial state when scroll down the customized list view.Can any one know please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using a different view holder for every line, and that when recycling your list item views your holders are shuffled togheter.

You can see this simply adding a `final int position` field to your holder, where to store the getView position parameter; debugging, you will see what happen.

So, **you can't use holders to store your quantity values**

Furthermore, you are not using the variable `list` to store quantity values. This code is working for me:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_custom, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.order = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.order);
        holder.item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        holder.order_qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.order_count);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    try{
        HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);

        holder.item_name.setText(map.get("name"));
        holder.order_qty.setText(map.get("quantity"));

        //Log.v("Available or not", ""+map.get("available"));


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    holder.order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //here am click the button to change order count text value
            int qty = Integer.valueOf(list.get(position).get("quantity"));

            qty++;

            holder.order_qty.setText(""+String.valueOf(qty));
            list.get(position).put("quantity", qty+"");
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: after i post the question i found the solution.Like what you did.anyway Thank you paolo.

Comment: can you post/comment the solution to your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The reason of the issue is described in the previous answer, however the suggested code block did not help resolving the problem in my case.

I added 350 records to my list view and one adapter object has four EditTexts.

Unexpected behaviors were occurring with TextWatcher listener always.

I used focus check listener to solve this problem:

```
holder.priceView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (!hasFocus)
                    {
                       // saving data on focus loss.
                       p.setPrice(holder.priceView.getText().toString());
                    }
                }
            });

// holder is my ViewHolder object , priceView is a editText in holder object, p is a reference of my data model.
```

This works, but the real time updates can be not as expected - like text watchers.

And there is the worst case, when firing last action (without focus losing, last edited value is not triggered and updated).