# Textview values is deleted in listview while scrolling the listview in android?

Tags: java, android

i have a listview with a row that row contains one imageview and 3 layouts and each layout contains again 3 textviews

the xml is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".05"
            android:src="@drawable/divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvVal"
                android:layout_width="20dip"
                android:layout_height="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/circel"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="99.99"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Laundry"
                android:textColor="#3A9ED4"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".05"
            android:src="@drawable/divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvVal1"
                android:layout_width="20dip"
                android:layout_height="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/circel"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="99.99"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Dry Clean"
                android:textColor="#3A9ED4"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".05"
            android:src="@drawable/divider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvVal2"
                android:layout_width="20dip"
                android:layout_height="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/circel"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="99.99"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Stream Iron"
                android:textColor="#3A9ED4"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and i take on Custom Adapter like this i get the some string values from server and that values is setted in listview

here the code is

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> p_id;
    ArrayList<String> p_name;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> imageId;
    ArrayList<String> wash_v;
    ArrayList<String> dry_v;
    ArrayList<String> iron_v;
    Typeface tf;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Intent i;
    float washItemCount = 0.0f;
    String iconName;
    Handler handler;
    Runnable myRunnable;
    Vector<BasketDO> vecBasket = new Vector<BasketDO>();
    int countVal1, countVal2, countVal3;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    ArrayList<String> laundry = null;
    ArrayList<String> streamIron = null;
    ArrayList<String> dryClean = null;
    int KEY;

    static int value1 = 0;
    static int value2 = 0;
    static int value3 = 0;

    DbaseHandler dbaseHandler;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> laundryHashmap;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> ironHashmap ;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> dryCleanHashmap ;

    public CustomAdapter(Context con, ArrayList<String> pid,
            ArrayList<String> pname, ArrayList<String> pimg,
            ArrayList<String> wash, ArrayList<String> dry,
            ArrayList<String> iron, int KEY) {
        p_id = pid;
        context = con;
        p_name = pname;
        imageId = pimg;
        wash_v = wash;
        dry_v = dry;
        iron_v = iron;
        this.KEY = KEY;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        laundryHashmap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        ironHashmap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        dryCleanHashmap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageId.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;
        ImageView img;
        LinearLayout ll1, ll2, ll3, llRow;
    }

    @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder vh = null;
        if (convertView == null) {



            vh = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic, parent, false);
            vh.ll1 = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll1);
            vh.ll2 = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll2);
            vh.ll3 = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll3);
            vh.llRow = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llRow);
            vh.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            vh.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
            vh.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv5);
            vh.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

            convertView.setTag(vh);
        }

        else
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        vh.tv1.setText(wash_v.get(position));
        vh.tv2.setText(iron_v.get(position));
        vh.tv3.setText(dry_v.get(position));
        ImageView image = vh.img;
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageId.get(position), image);

        final TextView tvVal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvVal);
        final TextView tvVal1 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvVal1);
        final TextView tvVal2 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvVal2);
        if (Appconstants.laundryHashmap != null
                && Appconstants.laundryHashmap.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Appconstants.laundryHashmap.size(); i++) {
                tvVal.setText(""+Appconstants.laundryHashmap.get(i));
            }

        }
        if (Appconstants.ironHashmap != null
                && Appconstants.ironHashmap.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Appconstants.ironHashmap.size(); i++) {
                tvVal1.setText(""+Appconstants.ironHashmap.get(i));
            }

        }
        if (Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap != null
                && Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap.size(); i++) {
                tvVal2.setText(""+Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap.get(i));
            }

        }

        i = new Intent("com.example.safewash");

        vh.ll1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                int count = 0;

                String washItem = wash_v.get(position);
                int washItems = Integer.parseInt(washItem);

                if (washItems != 0) {
                    int colorStart = Color.LTGRAY;
                    int colorEnd = 0;

                    ValueAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v,
                            "backgroundColor", colorStart, colorEnd);
                    animator.setDuration(800);
                    animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
                    animator.setRepeatCount(0);
                    animator.start();

                    washItemCount = Float.parseFloat(washItem);

                    tvVal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    count = Integer.parseInt(tvVal.getText().toString());
                    countVal1 = ++count;

                    i.putExtra("washItemCount", washItemCount);
                    i.putExtra("countVal1", countVal1);
                    context.sendBroadcast(i);

                    laundryHashmap.put(position, countVal1);
                    Appconstants.laundryHashmap = laundryHashmap;

                    if (Appconstants.laundryHashmap != null
                            && Appconstants.laundryHashmap.size() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Appconstants.laundryHashmap.size(); i++) {

                            value1 = Appconstants.laundryHashmap.get(position);
                            tvVal.setText("" + value1);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        vh.ll2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                int count = 0;
                String washItem = iron_v.get(position);

                washItemCount = Float.parseFloat(washItem);
                int washItems = Integer.parseInt(washItem);
                if (washItems != 0) {
                    int colorStart = Color.LTGRAY;
                    int colorEnd = 0;
                    ValueAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v,
                            "backgroundColor", colorStart, colorEnd);
                    animator.setDuration(800);
                    animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
                    animator.setRepeatCount(0);
                    animator.start();
                    washItemCount = Float.parseFloat(washItem);

                    tvVal1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    count = Integer.parseInt(tvVal1.getText().toString());
                    countVal2 = ++count;
                    // tvVal1.setText("" + countVal2);
                    i.putExtra("washItemCount", washItemCount);
                    i.putExtra("countVal2", countVal2);
                    context.sendBroadcast(i);
                    tvVal1.setText("" + countVal2);

                    ironHashmap.put(position, countVal2);
                    // int val = ironHashmap.get(position);

                    Appconstants.ironHashmap = ironHashmap;

                    if (Appconstants.ironHashmap != null
                            && Appconstants.ironHashmap.size() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Appconstants.ironHashmap.size(); i++) {

                            value2 = Appconstants.ironHashmap.get(position);

                            tvVal1.setText("" + value2);

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        vh.ll3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                int count = 0;
                String washItem = dry_v.get(position);
                washItemCount = Float.parseFloat(washItem);
                int washItems = Integer.parseInt(washItem);
                if (washItems != 0) {
                    int colorStart = Color.LTGRAY;
                    int colorEnd = 0;

                    ValueAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v,
                            "backgroundColor", colorStart, colorEnd);
                    animator.setDuration(800);
                    animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
                    animator.setRepeatCount(0);
                    animator.start();

                    washItemCount = Float.parseFloat(washItem);

                    tvVal2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    count = Integer.parseInt(tvVal2.getText().toString());
                    countVal3 = ++count;
                    i.putExtra("washItemCount", washItemCount);
                    i.putExtra("countVal3", countVal3);
                    context.sendBroadcast(i);
                    dryCleanHashmap.put(position, countVal3);
                    Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap = dryCleanHashmap;

                    if (Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap != null
                            && Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap.size() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap.size(); i++) {

                            value2 = Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap.get(position);
                            tvVal2.setText("" + value3);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

But here my problem is when click on the linearlayout the value will be incremented by one it is working fine and that value is also stored in hashmap based on position,but when i scroll the listview up and down the values is clearing how we can issue the problem

help me guys

thank in Advance....

Comment: it is a common issue .... developers are facing .... use holder to avoid ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780180/text-values-are-changed-in-customized-listview-when-scroll-the-listview-in-andro

Comment: here i have one more textview in side a linearlayout that is invisible when i click on the layout the textview is visible and the value is inxcremented by 1like that

Comment: declare `tvVal,tvVal1,tvVal2 `and `image` in your holder class as you do for other variable and use it.

Answer (score 0):

can you place this below code in if block

```
     tvVal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvVal);
     tvVal1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvVal1);
     tvVal2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvVal2);
```

and declare the textview in viewholder class

```
TextView tvVal,tvVal1,tvVal2;
```

Comment: when i place  the this code in if condition how we can setthe values like tvVal.setText its showing create the field

Comment: using View holder object you can set values to these view

Comment: when you scroll up new views are created and then if you scroll down again then the view is taken that is already created and it is tagged in Vh it  will execute else condition (for created view).

Comment: i am setted the tvval value inside onclick method ,vh is not taken over there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88979/discussion-between-rajsundar-and-manikanta-reddy).

Answer (score 0):

your `ViewHolder` should looks like this:

```
static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv1, tv2, tv3,tvVal1,tvVal2,tvVal3;
        ImageView image;
        LinearLayout ll1, ll2, ll3, llRow;
    }
```

Now update the following code as:

```
  if (convertView == null) {
       //other viewholder reference
        vh.tvVal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvVal);
        vh.tvVal1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvVal1);
        vh.tvVal2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvVal2);
        vh.image=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)
    }
```

Now update your else part as:

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageId.get(position), vh.image);

if (Appconstants.laundryHashmap != null
        && Appconstants.laundryHashmap.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Appconstants.laundryHashmap.size(); i++) {
        vh.tvVal.setText(""+Appconstants.laundryHashmap.get(i));
    }

}
if (Appconstants.ironHashmap != null
        && Appconstants.ironHashmap.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Appconstants.ironHashmap.size(); i++) {
        vh.tvVal1.setText(""+Appconstants.ironHashmap.get(i));
    }

}
if (Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap != null
        && Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap.size(); i++) {
        vh.tvVal2.setText(""+Appconstants.dryCleanHashmap.get(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: ok fine when i click on linearlayout i want to visible the textview so i write like this tvval.setVisibility(View,VISIBLE); this tvVal is available inside the onClick method so how we can get the tvVal herer

Comment: in your `xml` file set visibility property as gone for the view that you don't want in your view to be appear at first time.

Comment: the textview will deleting when i scroolling the listview