# TextView value of the list view items shuffle while scrolling in customized list-view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using a customized list view in my application. I have list of items to be displayed. For each cell I need to show the "Title of the Item", "Description of the Item", and "Count".

[image]

The data is displayed correctly when list is launched for the first time. When I scroll the list the count of each cell item shuffle with each other, whereas the title and description is displayed correctly only count gets shuffle when scrolled.

**adapter class code for** `GetView()`

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
  var item = tableItems[position];
  ViewHolder holder;
  View view = convertView;
  LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.From(mContext);
  if(view==null)
   {
      view = layoutInflator.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_cell, null);
      holder=new ViewHolder();
      holder.mTvTitleName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_title);
      holder.mTvDescriptionName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_description);
      holder.mTvCount = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.tv_Count);
      view.Tag=holder
   }
   else
   {
      holder = (ViewHolder)view.Tag;
   }
  return view;
}
```

I gone through the similar links :

[Text values are changed in customized listview when scroll the listview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780180/text-values-are-changed-in-customized-listview-when-scroll-the-listview-in-andro)

It is suggested to use `final` keyword. But in `C#` there is no `final` keyword instead there is `const` but `const` variable require to be initialised with certain value.

Can anyone suggest the correct approach to do this in xamarin.android.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with virtualization. Can you turn virtualization off for the list view in order to confirm this? (I'm not really into xamarin, so I'm not quite sure if thats the point and how to fix it)

Comment: sorry grek40, I didn't get your point. Where I need to set this property of Virtualization, I could not find any property in my list view object

Comment: Well, as I said I don't know much about xamarin and it seems what I suggested is not possible (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22472/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-virtualization-in-listview)